# how to write continuously into a text file created in a QThread?

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I I have written a program in C++ in qt and after several hours of working my program crashes suddenly and I don't know why.

I was curious to find out the reason so I said to my self to use a file and write my program Logs into it. so if it crashes I can see what's been going wrong and fix it. I didn't want to use the console. since it will become thousands of lines of information which I prefer to have them in a text file rather than qt console.

I cannot use a single open and close for my debug file because if my program suddenly crashes, the debug file will not have any information and it will become an empty text file so I wrote this Thread to store my program Log with multiple closing and opening :

```
QFile *Debug_File;
QTextStream *Debug_File_Interface;

DebugClass::DebugClass(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"DebugClass Thread is started .... \n";
    Debug_File = new QFile("Debug_Details.txt");
    Debug_File_Interface = new QTextStream(Debug_File);
    Debug_File->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    *Debug_File_Interface<<"Starting ..... "<<"\n";
    Debug_File->flush();
    Debug_File->close();
}

void DebugClass::run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        for( ; Log_VEC.size()>0 ; )
        {

            Debug_File->open(QIODevice::Append);
            *Debug_File_Interface<<Log_VEC[0]<<"\n";
            Debug_File->flush();
            Debug_File->close();
            QMutexLocker Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
            Log_VEC.erase(Log_VEC.begin());
            Locker.unlock();

        }
    }
}
```

and I call this thread in my CPP files like this:

X1.cpp

```
X1::Function1()
{

//Process1
 ....
//End Of Process1

      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process1Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
//Process2
 ....
//End Of Process2
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process2Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
}

X1::Function2()
{

//Process3
...
//end of Process3
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process3Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
//Process4
 ....
//End Of Process4
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process4Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
}
```

X2.cpp

```
X2::Function1()
{

//Process1
 ....
//End Of Process1

      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process1Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
//Process2
 ....
//End Of Process2
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process2Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
}

X2::Function2()
{

//Process3
...
//end of Process3
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process3Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
//Process4
 ....
//End Of Process4
      QMutexLocker Log_Locker(&LOG_VEC_MUTEX);
      Log_VEC.push_back(Process4Log);
      Log_Locker.unlock();    
}
```

and this goes the same for other cpp files. when I run my program just for some minute to see if it works or not, I realize that there is only one line written in the text file and it is the the line which I wrote in the constructor of my Thread class !!!

why nothing is put into the text file ? this is part of a big project and I want to make sure everything goes well by checking this log file.

Thanks

Comment: While loggings are a great help for larger programs, don't forget that there are tools like valgrind and static analysis programs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) to help prevent bugs that cause crashes at some unexpected point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm Closing each text file, QTextStream class remains connected to the first object I created in the constructor so nothings is written into the text file every time I open the text file.

Changing Thread Code to this block solved it:

```
    Debug_File->open(QIODevice::Append);
    Debug_File_Interface = new QTextStream(Debug_File);
    *Debug_File_Interface<<Log_VEC[0]<<"\n";
    Debug_File->flush();
    Debug_File->close();
```

Comment: Sorry I was hanging in this for hours !!! so I post the answer to help those who might get stuck in this in the near future ...